# Not well-formed: the end-tag for element type xs:element must end with a '>' delimiter

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have created XML files and associated XSD Schemas but the online verifier said it still remains errors in my XSD Schemas.

The exact error it shows is:

```
Not well-formed: the end-tag for element type 
xs:element" must end with a '>' delimiter.
```

Here is the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3schools.org/2001/XMLSchema/">

<xs:element name="List_Of_Skills" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>

    <xs:element name="Skill" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>

    <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>

    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element name="Skill">

 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element name="List_Of_Skills">

</xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3schools.org/2001/XMLSchema/">
```

By the way my XML code is well formed so I don't understand why my XSD code isn't valid even if I thought I understood how it works.

Comment: Just Paste your xsd, we will format it for you.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't work with "give me your email and I'll mail you my stuff and you can fix it for me". We're not your personal programming assistants or code writing servants. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and visiting the [help] to become more familiar with this site before posting your next question here.

Comment: Excuse me I tried to paste my code but I can't post my message with it inside, even if I add 4 spaces before the code or press CTRL + K so ... (yes, I looked for help on the '?' but with my english ...)

And I'm not asking to do something for me I have done my work I just don't know how I can solve the error I get and I can't go straight in my work if my XSD schemas isn't validated ...

No offense, I just wanted to make it easier but if you can explain another way to post my XSD code on this post ? Thanks

Comment: This is the shortest XSD I have created and I have the same error message for each XSD schema so if you know where the error is on that one, for sure I can solve others alone... Thank you for your help

Comment: I have done what you suggest but now I have the error "the end tag for element type "xs:schema" must end with a '>' delimiter"

I just have to change my xs namespace which the one you wrote and remove maxOccurs from the line 
<xs:element name="List_Of_Skills">  right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your XSD itself is not well-formed. Here's what you have to do to fix your XSD:**

1. Fix your end tags -- don't repeat attributes on end tags.
2. Fix the xs namespace prefix declaration; it should be
   `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`
3. Remove `maxOccurs="unbounded"` from root-level element declaration.

**Here are the above corrections applied to your XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="List_Of_Skills">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Skill" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:integer"/>
              <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help now I can begin the HTML part, thank you !

Comment: @IamjustaBeginner Why don't you *accept* the answer then?

Comment: (Thanks, lexicore.)  @IamjustaBeginner: Accepting an answer helps future readers by indicating that the answer worked for you.  It also increases the asker's and answer's [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), reflecting their helpfulness over time.  Read how to accept and more about accepting [**here**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215).  Thank you.

Comment: It's done, really sorry for my first day on this website a lot of mistakes from I ... Thank you again sir